# SQL Server stored procedure returns value in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have no experience with stored procedures whatsoever so I want to ask if something like this is possible.

Stored procedure returns

```
replace(rtrim(replace(
       replace(rtrim(replace(cast(@returningValue as varchar(40)), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
       , '.', ' ')), ' ', '.')
```

and this is called like this

```
SELECT storedProcedure(aDecimalValue)
FROM   Table
```

Comment: There may be a simple method to do this. What are you trying to do with `@returningValue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a `SCALAR VALUED` function..

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TEST_FUNCTION_NAME1 (@returningValue  VARCHAR(40)) 
        RETURNS VARCHAR(40) AS 
    BEGIN 
    return replace(rtrim(replace(
       replace(rtrim(replace(cast(@returningValue as varchar(40)), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
       , '.', ' ')), ' ', '.')

    END
```

Then you could do some thing like

```
SELECT dbo.TEST_FUNCTION_NAME1(string)
```